# Create domain user offline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, users

Can I add domain users to a database, when Sql Server **A** (the *development* server) is not part of the domain and has absolutely no access to the domain?

The domain users are of course not expected to work on server **A**, but these users are already configured on Sql Server **B**, the *production* sql server.

When a backup is taken on the *development* server **A** and deployed on the *production* server **B**, currently these users have to be re-added to the database on server **B**.

(The users do not have sysadmin rights on server B. As far as I know, if they had sysadmin rights, they would automatically have rights to access any new databases anyway)

Is it somehow possible to `CREATE USER domain\xy` on *development* server **A**, so that they will work when restoring a backup on the *production* server **B**?

Or as a workaround, could I take a blank database backup with only the users from server **B**, and then use that backup as a base to create new databases on server **A**?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: your workaround is fine, other than that: no.

## Long answer:

It is not possible to create a user for a non existing domain, though the error message is somewhat strange:

```
CREATE USER [INVALIDNAME\SOMEUSER] FOR LOGIN [VALIDNAME\SOMEUSER] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
Msg 15006, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
'INVALIDNAME\SOMEUSER' is not a valid name because it contains invalid characters.
```

- Running the same with "VALIDNAME" domain on both user and login side
  works fine.
- even if it would work, it would create a bunch of other issues for you (SID of INVALIDNAME\SOMEUSER not valid, mapped to wrong login, etc)

### Your Workaround

With your workaround, on the other hand, it will be okay as the users are not touched when you restore the database on any server.

### Another Workaround

Create a staging instance in the same domain as server B is, create all logins you need and create a database that contains all the users mapped to the logins you need.

Then, restore both, the master and your database, in a new instance running outside your domain.

I haven't tested this, but I am quite sure it should work.